# Pooling survey years in random forests

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, random-forest, pooling, cross-section

I am currently trying to predict household wealth in a random forest, using survey data.

My problem is the number of the observations. I have the option to either choose single years (n=4.000) or pooled years (n=20.000).
When pooling years, the survey year receives little importance scores, but is considered by the model.
Is it possible to perform the analysis with pooled years, arguing for sample size and explaining the restriction of pooling? Or should I never pool years?

I don't receive statistical significance for single years.